# Can __setattr__() can be defined in a class with __slots__?

Tags: python, python-internals, slots, setattr

Say I have a class which defines `__slots__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ['x']

    def __init__(self, x=1):
        self.x = x

    # will the following work?
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'x':
            object.__setattr__(self, name, -value) # Haha - let's set to minus x
```

Can I define `__setattr__()` for it?

Since `Foo` has no `__dict__`, what will it update?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All your code does, apart from negate the value, is call the parent class `__setattr__`, which is exactly what would happen without your `__setattr__` method. So the short answer is: Sure you can define a `__setattr__`.

What you cannot do is redefine `__setattr__` to use `self.__dict__`, because instances of a class with slots do not *have* a `__dict__` attribute. But such instances *do* have a `self.x` attribute, it's contents are just not stored in a dictionary on the instance.

Instead, slot values are stored in the same location a `__dict__` instance dictionary would otherwise be stored; on the object heap. Space is reserved for `len(__slots__)` references, and [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) on the class access these references on your behalf.

So, in a `__setattr__` hook, you can just call those descriptors directly instead:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if key == 'x':
        Foo.__dict__[key].__set__(self, -value)
```

Interesting detour: yes, on classes without a `__slots__` attribute, there *is* a descriptor that would give you access to the `__dict__` object of instances:

```
>>> class Bar(object): pass
... 
>>> Bar.__dict__['__dict__']
<attribute '__dict__' of 'Bar' objects>
>>> Bar.__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(Bar(), Bar)
{}
```

which is how *normal* instances can look up `self.__dict__`. Which makes you wonder where the `Bar.__dict__` object is found. In Python, it is [turtles all the way down](https://twitter.com/adamleonard/status/161852448368103424), you'd look *that* object up on the `type` object of course:

```
>>> type.__dict__['__dict__']
<attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects>
>>> type.__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(Bar, type)
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Bar' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Bar' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

Comment: does __dict__ work here? is that because the effective address of __dict__ and the heap items is the same, and this is kind of an easter egg? or did you mean __slots__?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: do not confuse the `__dict__` of the **class** with that of the **instance**. Instances of the class `Foo` do not have a `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: And `Foo` instances have no `__dict__` attribute, because `Foo.__dict__['__dict__']` raises a `KeyError`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - not sure I got this. Does `object` have a `__dict__` even though `Foo` does not? I'm guessing not, in which case, what does calling `object.__setattr__()` change?

Comment: Ahh... i see, i missed that you were accessing it through the class (`Foo.__dict__`) instead of `self.__dict__`. that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @bavaza: `object.__dict__` does exist, but that's not what an instance would use. `object.__setattr__` would look for data descriptors before it would look for `instance.__dict__`, and `Foo.__dict__['x']` *is* a data descriptor (it has both `__get__` and `__set__` hooks), so `instance.__dict__` is never looked up by `object.__setattr__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Turtles all the way down...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) until you reach Logo  Funny enough, yesterday I read [these other historical outlines](http://boveyking.blogspot.com/2006/01/?m=1). I think they deserve a merge. Thanks for the ref.